# getting last tweet posted on the twitter account

Tags: twitter

I am creating a windows widget in which I can get the last tweets posted on my web page.is there some way to get the last tweet posted.all the code I have found on the web doesn't seem to be working.thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got the solution.go to the twitter setting and select widget.now create the widget.

after this come back to the settings and click on widget again.you will see your widget there.under the widget you will see some code which you can copy into your html and it works.